# Are there any python libraries which can parse filesystem structures?

Tags: python, filesystems

I was checking for available python libraries which can work on filesystems. I know about pyfilesystem, but I am looking for something as below :

a) Can understand the partition table on a disk,
b) Can read data structures such as superblocks and understand the type of FS on the partition.
c) Can dump FS details onto screen/file etc..
d) Can parse different FS datastructures.

So, in short, I'm not looking for a library with which I can work on files, but rather a library which can work with the underlying filesystem structure. I've been searching, but didnt come across anything.

Does anyone know about tools with similar features ?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: A quick google for `python parse mbr` yields some results for the partition table. Not sure about the rest.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html Is this helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

[pyparted](https://fedorahosted.org/pyparted/) can do some of the things you ask for.

Comment: Yes, I checked pyparted before coming here. Since the doc seems to be lagging, I wasn't able to make much out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out MBR Parser:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gleeda/misc-scripts/master/misc_python/mbr_parser.py

Also, here's some decent FAT parsers:

https://github.com/mk-fg/fgtk/blob/master/desktop/vfat_shuffler

https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/master/construct/formats/filesystem/fat16.py